# Looping calculations in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a loop to iterate through each row and I want it to add up the values for each column in each row and sum them at the end.  I know how to do it as a formula but I am new to VBA.  I want it to sum the values multiply by a weight factor for columns B-F then output the values in column G.  I know I need to use a for loop to iterate through every row that is not blank as that amount will be changing as the sheet is updated. The formula version would be:

```
`=((5*(i,1))+(4*(i,2))+(3*(i,3))+(2*(i,4))+(1*(i,5))`
```

and I want this value output into cells(i,6)

So far I have:

```
`set wbk1 = Application.ActiveWorkbook
lr = wbk1.Sheets("sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 to Rows.Count
If i < lr Then
End If
Next i`
```

The formula part in the middle of the loop is where I am stuck at I believe.

Thanks!

Comment: So, e.g. G1=5*B1 + 4*C1 + 3*D1 + 2*E1 + 1*F1 ? If so, what exactly is the problem? Have you tried writing the formula in Excel and recording a macro? You might want to consider SUMPRODUCT.

Comment: this will give you the result of how many rows you have filled`lstrw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`
This will count all the rows in the sheet `rws = Rows.Count`, they probably will never match

Comment: Yes @SJR that is what i want but then for row 2 and 3 and so on for every row that is on the sheet ("i").  In just unsure how to do it in a loop using i.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You can use Range or Cells notation, but in this case the latter seems more intuitive. That said, you would be better off using worksheet formulae for this.

```
Sub x()

Dim wbk1 As Workbook
Dim lr As Long, i As Long

Set wbk1 = Application.ActiveWorkbook

With wbk1.Sheets("Sheet3")
    lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lr
        .Cells(i, "G") = 5 * .Cells(i, "B") + 4 * .Cells(i, "C") + 3 * .Cells(i, "D") + _
                      2 * .Cells(i, "E") + .Cells(i, "F")
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Im getting a type mismatch for `.Cells(i, "G") = 5 * .Cells(i, "B") + 4 * .Cells(i, "C") + 3 * .Cells(i, "D") + _
                      2 * .Cells(i, "E") + .Cells(i, "F")`

Comment: OK so one or more are not numbers. Probably should build in a check for that.

Comment: I have column and row titles "requirement 1, 2, 3 etc." for columns in row 1 and project A B C etc. for Rows in column A. Maybe that is why?

Comment: Ya it worked when i took out the column headers in row 1! But how do i get it to start with Column B and Row 2 rather than (1,1)

Comment: Start your loop from 2 then.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much that worked perfectly! Really appreciate it